# Jamais (un) gémissement

Tags: articles, littérature

Bonjour,

Dans *[Amour](https://athena.unige.ch/athena/maupassant/maupassant-amour.html)* de Maupassant :

> *Jamais gémissement* de souffrance ne me déchira le cœur comme l’appel
> désolé, comme le reproche lamentable de ce pauvre animal perdu dans
> l’espace.

Est-ce que les deux formes *jamais gémissement* / *jamais* *un gémissemet* sont correctes ?

Je ne comprends pas très bien l'absence de l'article ici.

Comment: On trouve ce genre de construction lorsque l'on évoque un type, une forme de gémissement, sans évoquer le gémissement lui-même.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Le bon usage* signale qu'il est possible d'omettre l'article « devant des noms exprimant non quelque individualité concrète, déterminée, mais une conception générale de l'esprit. » Un des exemples donnés est :

> Jamais baigneurs n'étaient venus dans les parages (Pierre Loti, *Le Roman d’un enfant*).

C'est exactement le cas présent dans la phrase de Maupassant où  il n'est pas question d'un gémissement en particulier mais de la notion de gémissement. L’omission de l'article dans ce cas n'est pas obligatoire. Maupassant aurait aussi pu écrire « Jamais un gémissement de souffrance ne me déchira le cœur...  ». L'absence d'article est littéraire, c'est en harmonie avec le style littéraire de Maupassant.

Ce cas d'omission de l'article est très fréquent dans les proverbes et dictons, justement parce qu'ils expriment des généralités.

> Chat ganté ne prit jamais souris.
> À cheval hargneux, étable à part.
> Cœur qui soupire n'a pas ce qu'il désire.
> Charbonnier est maître en sa loge.
> Homme sans abri, oiseau sans nid.
> Jamais grand nez n'a gâté beau visage.
> À cœur vaillant, rien d'impossible.
> Besogne commencée est plus qu'à demi faite.

(Note : pour trouver des exemples j'ai été fouillé dans *[Quelque six mille proverbes et aphorismes usuels empruntés à notre âge et aux siècles derniers](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k9780380s/f9.item.texteImage)* de Charles Cahier)